# Prove by induction: $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}:3\ |\ (6n^2-12n+3)$

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I'm not sure how to start this induction problem.

I  was told that we start doing induction by using a base case $n=1$.  Then we set $n=k$ to prove $n=k+1$.  But how do I prove that $6(k+1)^2-12(k+1)+3$ is divisible by $3$ if $6k^2-12k+3$ is?

I'm confused, can someone give me some help?  Thanks.

Comment: $6n^2-12n+3=3(2n^2-4n+1)$ why do we need induction?

Comment: yeah, you don't need induction.  see @labbhattacharjee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  If you have to use induction, you have the correct idea.  You assume $3\mid6k^2-12k+3$ and want to prove $3\mid6(k+1)^2-12(k+1)k+3$.  You make use of your assumption by finding it in the new expression.  So expand out the $(k+1)$'s and group the terms together to use the assumption.  Now you look at what is left and show that $3$ divides it, too.

Answer (score -1):

You can also proceed as follows:

Prove this for $n=1$.

Assume $3|(6k^2-12k+3)$.

Then $6(k+1)^2-12(k+1)k+3 = 3(2(k+1)^2-4(k+1)+1)$ which is divisible by $3$.

And you're done.

The idea of induction is that you assume $P(n)$ is true for some $k$ and then prove it for $k+1$. If you prove it for $k+1$ without using the induction hypothesis, it is still a valid induction argument since you first assumed $P(n)$ is true for some $k$ and then proved it for $k+1$.

Comment: The think I don't like about this is that you don't actually use induction at all. You just rewrite the statement and provide a direct proof that doesn't rely on the base case, nor the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: @mixedmath And yet it is still a correct induction argument. Clearly, the statement given can be easily proved using the distributive property but the question asks to prove it using the proof structure of mathematical induction which is what I've done. Honestly, you can set up questions such as: 'Prove $P\implies Q$ is true' where the $Q$ happens to be some tautology. You suppose $P$ and then since $Q$ is true, you've proved the statement. Here it would be unwelcome to state that you haven't used the assumption $P$ at all.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain his downvote?